# Problems Appending Columns to the bottom of data

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to cut columns G through I (without header) and paste the data starting on the next available line under columns D through F. Basically, I want to append the columns that are *adjacent* to be *beneath*, instead. Then I need to copy columns A through C and paste the duplicate data right beneath itself.

This code actually worked for 4 files of mine, but it's now giving me an error, saying that I should paste to the same size rectangle or a single cell. I've tried soooo much code that I've found on boards and nothing has fixed this error. There are no merged cells.

All help is greatly appreciated!

```
Dim lastRow As String
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("G2:I" & LastR).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("A2:C" & LastR).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: so, what is "LastR" ' value

Comment: Dim LastR As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Try this comment below your second line "activesheet.cells.unmerge"

Answer (score 0):

Try this comment below your second line activesheet.cells.unmerge
It will unmerge all cell in sheet.
Also dont forget to check value of last row and Lastr.
Smt likes this will work.
If lastrow<2 then 
lastrow=2 
End if